# Почему сбиваются стили CSS при копировании прямой ссылки в браузер? CSS , PHP, MySQL

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

Почему сбиваются стили CSS при копировании прямой ссылки в браузер? CSS , PHP, MySQL
Если через index нажать по картинке, то всё открывается нормально, c CSS стилями
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я перешел по ссылке и понял в чем проблема. У вас указаны пути к файлам относительно текущего каталога, а не корневого.
Допустим у вас:
`vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`
А нужно:
`/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css`